# Python - beautifulsoup -> Multiple HTML files into one CSV file

Tags: python, html, csv, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use beautifulsoup to write/append to one CSV file. Each time I run this script, I want it to be overwritten from scratch, then appends all the HTML files to the CSV file. But currently, I am only seeing data from the last HTML file (File3.html) in the CSV file and not the others. Can someone help me figure this out. Here is my script below. Also, if anyone can help me find a better way of calling the HTML files - like maybe calling a directory instead of me typing in each file name (40 file names), that would be great too. Thank!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

with open('C:\HTML\File1.html'), open('C:\HTML\File2.html'), open('C:\HTML\File3.html') as html_file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file, 'lxml')

#Find Program name and address
title = soup.find('div', class_='content-single-job_listing-hero-company col-md-7 col-sm-12')
program = str.strip(title.h1.text)
address = soup.find('div', class_='job_listing-location job_listing-location-formatted').get_text(separator=" ").strip()

#Find the tag containing Telephone and Fax
phone = soup.findAll('span')[31].text
fax = soup.findAll('span')[32].text
crisis1 = soup.find('div', class_='textwidget custom-html-widget')
if crisis1:
    crisis = str.strip(crisis1.findAll('p')[0].text)
else:
    crisis = "N/A"

#Find email
email = soup.findAll('span')[33].text

#About
about1 = soup.find('aside', class_='widget widget-job_listing listify_widget_panel_listing_content')
about = about1.findAll('p')[0].text

#Our Services
service1 = about1 = soup.find('aside', class_='widget widget-job_listing listify_widget_panel_listing_content')
service2 = service1.findAll('p')[2].text

# ACTION East delivers all services with clients
service3 = service1.findAll('ul')[0]
service4 = service3.findAll('li')

# Our Assertive Community Treatment (ACT) Program
service5 = service1.findAll('p')[3].text
service6 = service1.findAll('p')[4].text

# Our Substance Abuse Treatment Program
service7 = service1.findAll('p')[5].text
service8 = service1.findAll('p')[6].text

# Eligibility criteria for ACTION East
service9 = service1.findAll('p')[7].text
service10 = service1.findAll('p')[8].text
service11 = service1.findAll('ul')[1]
service12 = service11.findAll('li')

# How Do We Get Referrals?
service13 = service1.findAll('p')[10].text
service14 = service1.findAll('p')[11].text

#service5 = [e.string for e in service4]
#service6 = [elem.strip().split(';') for elem in service5]

# fields names
fields = []

# data rows of csv file

rows = program, address, phone, fax, crisis, email, about, service2, service4, service5 + " " + service6, service7 + " " + service8, service9 + " " + service10, service13 + " " + service14

# name of csv file
filename = "C:\CSV\Programs.csv"

# writing to csv file
with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile:
    # creating csv writer object
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter="|")

    # writing the fields
    #csvwriter.writerow(fields)

    # writing the data rows
    csvwriter.writerows([rows])
```

Comment: you have to open every file separatelly - in separated `with open() as html_file` - and run code for every `html_file` separatelly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to work with every file separatelly - and open only one file

You can use `for`-loop for this

```
for fullpath in [r'C:\HTML\File1.html', r'C:\HTML\File2.html', r'C:\HTML\File3.html']:
    
    with open(fullpath) as html_file:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file, 'lxml')

    # ... code ...
```

and you can append rows to list and after `for`-loop you can write all

Later you can use `for`-loop with `os.listdir()`, `os.walk()` or `glob.glob()` to work with all files in folder.

You should also use prefix `r` (for `raw` string) when you use path with `\` because `\` has special meaning in string ie. `\n`, `\t`, `\U`, `\b`, etc. (even in `path`) and sometimes it can make problem - ie. `\U` in `C:\Users`

---

I can't test it but it should be something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

# --- before `for`-loop ---

# fields names
#fields = []

all_rows = []

# --- `for`-loop ---

for fullpath in [r'C:\HTML\File1.html', r'C:\HTML\File2.html', r'C:\HTML\File3.html']:
    
    with open(fullpath) as html_file:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file, 'lxml')

    #Find Program name and address
    title = soup.find('div', class_='content-single-job_listing-hero-company col-md-7 col-sm-12')
    program = title.h1.text.strip()
    address = soup.find('div', class_='job_listing-location job_listing-location-formatted').get_text(separator=" ").strip()
    
    #Find the tag containing Telephone and Fax
    phone = soup.findAll('span')[31].text
    fax = soup.findAll('span')[32].text
    crisis1 = soup.find('div', class_='textwidget custom-html-widget')
    if crisis1:
        crisis = crisis1.findAll('p')[0].text.strip()
    else:
        crisis = "N/A"
    
    #Find email
    email = soup.findAll('span')[33].text
    
    #About
    about1 = soup.find('aside', class_='widget widget-job_listing listify_widget_panel_listing_content')
    about = about1.findAll('p')[0].text
    
    #Our Services
    service1 = about1 = soup.find('aside', class_='widget widget-job_listing listify_widget_panel_listing_content')
    service2 = service1.findAll('p')[2].text
    
    # ACTION East delivers all services with clients
    service3 = service1.findAll('ul')[0]
    service4 = service3.findAll('li')
    
    # Our Assertive Community Treatment (ACT) Program
    service5 = service1.findAll('p')[3].text
    service6 = service1.findAll('p')[4].text
    
    # Our Substance Abuse Treatment Program
    service7 = service1.findAll('p')[5].text
    service8 = service1.findAll('p')[6].text
    
    # Eligibility criteria for ACTION East
    service9 = service1.findAll('p')[7].text
    service10 = service1.findAll('p')[8].text
    service11 = service1.findAll('ul')[1]
    service12 = service11.findAll('li')
    
    # How Do We Get Referrals?
    service13 = service1.findAll('p')[10].text
    service14 = service1.findAll('p')[11].text
    
    #service5 = [e.string for e in service4]
    #service6 = [elem.strip().split(';') for elem in service5]
    
    # data rows of csv file

    row = [program, address, phone, fax, crisis, email, about, service2, service4, service5 + " " + service6, service7 + " " + service8, service9 + " " + service10, service13 + " " + service14]

    all_rows.append(row)
    
# --- after for-loop ---

# name of csv file
filename = r"C:\CSV\Programs.csv"

# writing to csv file
with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile:
    # creating csv writer object
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter="|")

    # writing the fields
    #csvwriter.writerow(fields)

    # writing the data rows
    csvwriter.writerows(all_rows)
```

---

**EDIT:**

For `os.listdir()` it can be

```
import os

folder = r'C:\HTML'

for filename in sorted(os.listdir(folder)):

    # skip files which have no extension `.html` or `.HTML`
    if not filenames.lower().endswith('.html'):
       continue

    fullpath = os.path.join(folder, filename)
    
    with open(fullpath) as html_file:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file, 'lxml')

    # ... code ...
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I now know about the r prefix thanks to you. But your script still only importing the last HTML file from the HTML call list. It's not including the first two HTML files.

Comment: it loads all files but you have to append all results to external list. If you will create new list inside `for`-loop then it will always remove previous content and you get data only from last HTML. I do this in my example. And you have to write file AFTER `for`-loop. If you will write inside `for`-loop then it will remove prevous content and you get data only from last HTML. I do this in my example.

Comment: thank you so much! I didn't have my indentions correct.